# Is it possible to access all cells not equal to the indexpath when using didSelectItemAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am new to Swift and new to coding, so please forgive me if my question is vague, or the answer is obvious.

I have a collectionView and a number of cells inside. When I select a cell, I want to change the color of every cell except the selected one. I'm using the delegate method: didSelectItemAtIndexPath. How might I be able to access the cells at indexpath not equal to the indexpath of the selected cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is, you can store your indexPath in a variable in class and reload your collection view in didSelectItemAtIndexPath after storing this indexPath. After that in your cellForItemAtIndexPath, check for this indexPath stored and change the color of cell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`visibleCells`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618056-visiblecells) property of the Collection View to get all the visible cells.  The property returns an array that you can iterate through and use [`indexPath(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618094-indexpath) to test to see if it is the one you do not want to color.

Then you need to make sure that you update other cells as the user scrolls by setting the proper color when providing new cells from your data source methods or using [`collectionView(_:willDisplay:forItemAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618087-collectionview).